# Why do I have two (2) launchers after customizing my Unity setup with ccsm, plese help?

Tags: unity, graphics

when i installed Ubuntu 11/10.and installed ccsm.
and run the command "compiz --replace" to take effects.but it gave the system like this>

[image]

Comment: Try to run "unity --replace" and see what happens? That may help

Comment: Other launcher belongs to wallpaper? Or it is unity 2d launcher? Else just restart your computer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dconf write /com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher 1
dconf write /com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher/use-strut true
```

worked for me; the use-strut may be unnecessary